# Speed up access to python programs from Golang's exec packaqe

Tags: python, go, exec, low-latency

I need suggestions on how to speed up access to python programs when called from Golang.  I really need fast access time (very low latency).

Approach 1:
func main() {
...
...
        cmd = exec.Command("python", "test.py")
        o, err = cmd.CombinedOutput()
...
}

If my test.py file is a basic print "HelloWorld" program, the execution time is over 50ms.  I assume most of the time is for loading the shell and python in memory.

Approach 2:
The above approach can be speeded up substantially by having python start a HTTP server and then gaving the Go code POST a HTTP request and get the response from the HTTP server (python).  Speeds up response times to less than 5ms.
I guess the main reason for this is probably because the python interpretor is already loaded and warm in memory.

Are there other approaches I can use similar to approach 2 (shared memory, etc.) which could speed up the response from my python code?.  Our application requires extremely low latency and the 50 ms I am currently seeing from using Golang's exec package is not going to cut it.

thanks,

Comment: I don't know much about Golang, but does it have support for opening a pipe to a command and keeping it open? That way, you could have only one instance of the python script stay running and listen on stdin, which is probably faster than the HTTP version.

Comment: Transpile your Python code to Go with grumpy. Or use a Python interpreter in your Go code or call out to C-Python directly via github.com/sbinet/go-python

Comment: @Volker Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, I can't do this. I mentioned Python but in reality the other process could be one of many (Python2.7, Python3.5, nodeJS, JS, Go itself, Java, Ruby, etc.)

Comment: @Niayesh Thanks for suggesting pipes. The Golang program that spawns the python process needs to collect three things from the python process (stdout and stderr logs and most important a response).  The response is most important and needs lowest latency. The logs can be collected slowly.  How can I do this using pipes?  I can create a bidirectional pipe and redirect stdout and stderr but how do I also get a response back from python to go.  E.g. The Golang process spawns a python process (python test.py). test.py is a user function that has stdout and stderr and returns a json response.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1: Simple HTTP server and client

Approach 2: Local socket or pipe

Approach 3: Shared memory

Approach 4: GRPC server and client

In fact, I prefer the GRPC method by stream way, it will hold the connection (because of HTTP/2), it's easy, fast and secure. And it's easy moving python node to another machine.